# How can I disable error parsing in specific file type in NetBeans

Tags: php, netbeans

In my project I have few .md files that should not be treated like code files (PHP project).
I have Error badges all over the place because there are "errors" in those files. Is there any way to disable error checking in specific files or whole file type?

I don't really want to exclude those file entirely from project. Hope there is way to just disable error checking in those files.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Go to Tools->Options, then go to the Miscellaneous Tab, then the Files tab. Click New next to File Extension and add `md`, then select `text/plain`.

Or right below you can add `.*\.md` to your ignored file pattern. If you do this then the files will not show up in Netbeans at all.

Comment: That was it. I don't know how I missed that option. Thank you very much. I hope it will help other people in future too.

Comment: great, should add google-fonts.css , this file always makes trouble